# In Ansible, how to set Execution-Policy to RemoteSigned?

Tags: powershell, ansible, powershell-2.0

I have an Ansible role that executes Powershell scripts. I do this

```
- name: Set the execution policy to Unrestricted first
  win_shell: Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force
  tags: always

- name: Start the services
  win_shell: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Start_Services.ps1
  args:
    chdir: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\
  when: exa_services_state == "started"
  tags: always

- name: Stop the services
  win_shell: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Stop_Services.ps1
  args:
    chdir: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\
  when: exa_services_state == "stopped"
  tags: always

- name: Set the execution policy to RemoteSigned
  win_shell: Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine -Force
  tags: always
```

However when the last task executes, I get the following

```
fatal: [10.227.26.97]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine -Force", "delta": "0:00:00.640619", "end": "2022-03-04 05:33:29.496843", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-03-04 05:33:28.856224", "stderr": "Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by \r\na policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective \r\nexecution policy of Unrestricted. Type \"Get-ExecutionPolicy -List\" to view your execution policy settings. For more \r\ninformation please see \"Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy\".\r\nAt line:1 char:65\r\n+ ... ing $false; Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope  ...\r\n+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand", "stderr_lines": ["Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by ", "a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective ", "execution policy of Unrestricted. Type \"Get-ExecutionPolicy -List\" to view your execution policy settings. For more ", "information please see \"Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy\".", "At line:1 char:65", "+ ... ing $false; Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope  ...", "+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException", "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

If I go on the node and execute `Get-ExecutionPolicy` I see

```
PS: C:\Users\myuser>Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

How can I avoid the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command actually succeeded(!) in principle, as evidenced by the wording of the error message.

If all you want to do is to set the local-machine policy for *future sessions*, you can simply *ignore* the error, by enclosing the statement in `try` / `catch`; also note the trailing `; exit 0` so as to ensure that exit code `0` is reported back to Ansible:

```
  win_shell: try { Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine -Force } catch { }; exit 0
```

Note: If you're confident that you're running with elevation (which setting the *machine* policy requires), an empty `catch` block, as above, is probably sufficient.

A robust solution requires a bit more work:

```
  win_shell: try { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine allSigned -force } catch { if ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -ne 'ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand') { throw } }; exit 0
```

This selectively ignores the anticipated error while re-throwing any others.

---

As an aside: It is unfortunate that the situation described by the error message, explained below, is surfaced as an *error*, let alone as a (statement)-*terminating* one. This is discussed in [GitHub issue #12032](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12032), but a decision was made to retain this behavior for the sake of backward compatibility.

What the message is trying to tell you is that your execution policy will not take effect - in your case *in the current session* - because it is preempted by a *less restrictive* policy in a scope with *higher precedence* - see the conceptual [about_Execution_Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) help topic.

Unfortunately, the error is also triggered for *ad hoc*, *process-specific* overrides (the `Process` scope), via the `powershell.exe` CLI's `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter, so that a command such as the following triggers it:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned
```

That is, the session in which the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command executes has a *process-specific* execution policy of `Bypass`, and because the `Process` scope has higher precedence than the `CurrentUser` scope, and because the `Bypass` policy is less restrictive than `RemoteSigned`, the error occurs.

Technically, *in that specific session itself* the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` doesn't take effect (because the process-specific `Bypass` overrides it), but it will in *future* sessions (unless overridden again) - and if the sole intent of the CLI call was to set the *persistent* execution policy for *future* sessions, the error is nothing but a confusing annoyance.

I presume you're seeing this error because Ansible is using `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` (or `Unrestricted`) behind the scenes when it processes `win_shell` commands.

Comment: @ChrisF, good point, I forgot about the exit code: simply append `; exit 0` to the `try` / `catch` statement. I've also updated the answer accordingly.